# How to do 21/2 on paper

Tags: arithmetic, divisibility

I looked at online tutorials and im stuck at this case.

21/2

First, 2 goes into 2 once, so put 1 in the quotient, 2*1 = 2 so 2-2 = 0. Now we bring the 1 in 21 down. 2 doesnt go into 0, so what do we do in this case?

When i looked online, they went straight to saying 2 goes into 21 10 times so put 10 on the quotient, and 21-20= 1 is the remainder. But I was taught to divide the divsor by the divident one digit at a time.

Comment: @vasya so is the quotient 10.0? Or 1.0? (Ie do we add the decimal after the 0 is added or before)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$
\require{enclose}
\begin{array}{r}
                10  \\[-3pt]
2 \enclose{longdiv}{21} \\[-3pt]
     \underline{2}\phantom{2} \\[-3pt]
                1  \\[-3pt]
     \underline{0}
\\1
\end{array}
$$

Now that we found out the quotient is $10$ and the remainder is $1$, the relationship is $$21=2(10)+1$$

$$\frac{21}{2}=10+\frac12=10.5$$

As we learn more maths, we learn more tricks and we speed things up. It should be  quite clear that $2(10)=20$ and $21-20=1$.

Comment: Using Remainder over divisor results in 10+1/2 or 10.5

Comment: We do not add a decimal in the quotient when we bring down the extra 0?

Comment: You can bring down $0$ if you want, but it doesn't change anything.

Comment: thank you @AaronM